Excel FILTER() function that includes a range of values
I've built a worksheet that takes a list of food for each meal and allows the user to select a series of meals and get a big list of the associated food.


I achieve this through a manual process of stitching FILTER() functions together like so
=VSTACK(
IF(C2="","",FILTER(Meals!C:C,Meals!A:A=C2,"")),
IF(C3="","",FILTER(Meals!C:C,Meals!A:A=C3,""))...
)

This isn't too flexible and if I have more than about 100 rows, the formula is too big for excel and it breaks... is there a better way to do this? FILTER() doesn't seem to take multiple lookups or a lookup range.
Is there a way to make FILTER() accept multiple includes (or a range) or a different formula I should be using?

Something like =FILTER(Meals!C:C,is number(xmatch(Meals!A:A,C2:C3)),"")

Perhaps for simplicity and readability I would use the following, with the help of COUNTIF() function:


=FILTER(Foodtbl[Food],COUNTIF(List[Selected list of food],Foodtbl[Meal]),"")


Also, instead of using ranges, I will convert the ranges into Structured References aka Tables so that whenever there is a change in the source data, it directly affects the formulas to update.
The Source Table is named as Foodtbl while the list is named as List

One other alternative, using ISNA() + XMATCH()
=FILTER(Foodtbl[Food],1-ISNA(XMATCH(Foodtbl[Meal],List[Selected list of food])))


One more alternative way is using MMULT() :
=FILTER(Foodtbl[Food],
 MMULT(N(Foodtbl[Meal]=TOROW(List[Selected list of food])),{1;1}))



With this formula:
=TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,BYROW(A11:A12,LAMBDA(xx,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(xx=A1:A9,B1:B9,""))))),"|",,TRUE))
the result is


Handle duplicate items; TOCOL is used to eliminate rows with NA() from duplicate items.
Parameters can be ranges or structured references (Table[Meal], Table[Food]).
=LAMBDA(meal, food, selected_meal,
    LET(
        matching_food, FILTER(food, COUNTIF(selected_meal, meal), NA()),
        result, TOCOL(
            IF(ISNA(matching_food), "none", SORT(UNIQUE(matching_food))),
            3
        ),
        result
    )
)(A2:A200, B2:B200, D2:D10)


